# When should a variable be declared in the header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header, integer, declaration

I have this class with a lot of functions (around 30) and each function declares a new integer value that is used to store the value from the conversion of a string from the stack to an integer. This means I keep declaring new integers so many times in the same class.

Here is an example of a function that declares these integers:

```
void Interpreter::add()
{
    val1 = std::stoi(stack.back());
    stack.pop_back();
    val2 = std::stoi(stack.back());
    stack.pop_back();

    stack.push_back(std::to_string(val1 + val2));
}

class Interpreter 
{
private:
    int val1, val2;

}
```

My question is: is it better to declare these variables only once in the header file and then re-use them in each function?

I'd like to know if there is some kind of convention on this matter.

Comment: This is not very clear, can you update your post with at least some lines of code?

Comment: Of course. I apologise!

Comment: A couple of popular conventions are "declare variables as close to their use as possible" and "don't add member variables just to save keystrokes".

Comment: I added some code. I hope my question can be better understood now. Thank you for these conventions @molbdnilo, but it doesn't fully answer my question yet.

Comment: A more important question is why you're using a stack of strings for doing arithmetic with integers. With a stack of integers, and your own "pop function", this would be a non-issue.

Comment: The goal of the assignment is to have a vector of strings. Only string values may be added to the stack. Not integers. It isn't my decision to do it this way.

Comment: What part of your question is not answered in the comment section?

Comment: The title of my post. Should I declare these variables in the header file?

Comment: How would you declare function local variables in the header?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64337937/edit) to show how you would "declare these variables in the header file", because I strongly suspect you're asking whether `val1`, etc. should be *members* of your class vs. automatic variables in the currently shown usage scope. In short, you're tossing about vernacular without understanding what is really being *heard* for want of what you think is being *said*.

Comment: Okay, I did. So I wonder if the way it is shown in my post now, is better following conventions. I'll use `val1` and `val2` in multiple functions like a substract function, a multiply function, but also the add function.

Comment: You asked a question and got an answer but you don't want to accept the answer: "declare variables as close to their use as possible" and "don't add member variables just to save keystrokes". That means: "Don't move function local variables into the class if it's not necessary".

Comment: I do want to accept it. I understand you now. However, my entire question is whether it would be necessary to put the variables in the header file?

Comment: `int val1 = std::stoi(stack.back());` declares the variable as close as possible. You can't declare it later.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll then keep it the way I have. Thank you for answering!

Comment: A downvote isn't necessary. I wasn't unclear with my question.. :(

Comment: IMHO, you should never declare global variables (variables outside a class) in a header file.  All source files that include the header file will get a copy of the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use member variables just to save on typing – you're going to encounter bugs that are incredibly hard to find.

Add a little abstraction,

```
int Interpreter::pop() 
{ 
    // Add error handling here.
    int i = std::stoi(stack.back());
    stack.pop_back();
    return i;
}

void Interpreter::push(int i)
{
    stack.push_back(std::to_string(i));
}
```

and then you can write

```
void Interpreter::add()
{
    push(pop() + pop());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.